# Mostrar layout diferente wordpress PHP si hay o no hay imagen destacada

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar un artículo con un layout totalmente diferente para los artículos que tengan imagen destacada y otro layout, para los artículos que no tiene imagen destacada

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo así dentro de tu template:

single.php

```
<?php

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            get_template_part('views/post-with-featured-image');
        } else {
            get_template_part('views/post-without-featured-image');
        }
    }
}

get_footer();
```

views/post-with-featured-image.php

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
```

views/post-without-featured-image.php

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```